# Building conilpotent coalgebras from co-square-zero-extensions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, deformation-theory, model-categories, coalgebras

Let $\mathrm{K}$ be a field of char. 0.

Given a chain complex $\mathrm{X} $ over $\mathrm{K}$ denote $\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{X})$ the co-square-zero-extension on $\mathrm{X}, $ i.e. the 
cocommutative non-counital dg-coalgebra structure on $\mathrm{X} $ with zero-comultiplication.

We think of the $\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{X})$ as the most basic 
conilpotent cocommutative non-counital dg-coalgebras.

Is it true that every conilpotent cocommutative non-counital dg-coalgebra can be iterately built of co-square-zero-extensions using 
homotopy pushouts and filtered colimits?

Here we implicitely use that the model structure on chain complexes over $\mathrm{K}$ with weak equivalences the quasi-isos lifts to a model structure on the category of  conilpotent cocommutative non-counital dg-coalgebras.

Comment: Consider the conilpotent cocommutative noncounital coalgebra $C(n)$ concentrated in the cohomological degree 0, with zero differential, with a $k$-linear basis $c_1$, $\dots$, $c_n$ and the comultiplication $\mu(c_m)=\sum_{p+q=m}c_p\otimes c_q$.  How would you produce this coalgebra by homotopy pushouts and filtered colimits?  What is it a homotopy pushout of?  Or a filtered colimit of?

Comment: First of all thanks for the comment. My question was a bit vague formulated. I consider homotopy pushouts and filtered colimits of (trivial) co-square-zero extensions in a model structure on the category of conilpotent cocommutative non-counital dg-coalgebras that lifts the usual model structure on chain complexes over a field with weak equivalences the quasi-isos.

Comment: My question is the following: What is the smallest full subcategory of the category of of conilpotent cocommutative non-counital dg-coalgebras that contains all trivial co-square-zero-extensions and closed under homotopy pushouts and filtered colimits (and closed under weak equivalences)?  Of course if one would replace homotopy pushouts by pushouts in my question, one would not get something new as the full subactegory spanned by the trivial-co-square-zero-extensions is closed under small colimits.

Comment: In particular I ask if the free conilpotent cocommutative non-counital coalgebra $\mathrm{S}(\mathrm{X}) $ on a chain complex $\mathrm{X}$ (being the free non-unital symmetric algebra) belongs to the smallest full subcategory of the category of conilpotent cocommutative non-counital dg-coalgebras that contains all trivial co-square-zero-extensions and closed under homotopy pushouts and filtered colimits.

Comment: Homotopy pushouts in the lifted model structure on conilpotent cocommutative non-counital dg-coalgebras are calculated as homotopy pushouts in the usual model structure on chain complexes.

Comment: I don't know, but I would like to ask another question then: how do you know that there exists such a model structure on conilpotent dg-coalgebras?  If I understood it right, it should have quasi-isomorphisms as weak equivalences and -- injective morphisms as cofibrations?  Is it known that there is such a model structure on conilpotent cocommutative dg-coalgebras?

Comment: This follows from a theorem of a paper  "Model structures for coalgebras" https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5526 by Drummond-Cole and Hirsh applied to the cocommutative cooperad.

Comment: Exactly: The quasi-isomorphisms are the weak equivalences and the injective morphisms are the cofibrations of this model-structure.